# Elasticsearch - Sort by matching field, then date

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, querydsl, elasticsearch-query

I'm sorting Elasticsearch results in the following order:

1. Posts with a matching `tag`;
2. Posts with a matching `title`;
3. Posts with a matching `category`;
4. Posts with a matching `content`;

I've accomplished that with a `function_score` that increases the score based on the matching field:

```json
{
  function_score: {
    query: {
      bool: {
        should: [
        {
          match: {
            'insightsTag.title': {
              query: this.queryString,
              boost: 4
            }
          }
        },
        {
          match: {
            title: {
              query: this.queryString,
              boost: 3
            }
          }
        },
        {
          match: {
            'insightsCategory.title': {
              query: this.queryString,
              boost: 2
            }
          }
        },
        {
          match: {
            content: {
              query: this.queryString
            }
          }
        },
        ],
        must: [typeFilter]
      }
    },
    boost_mode: 'sum'
  }
}
```

How can I sort each of those matching groups by date? Ie. display all posts with a matching tag, sorted by date; then, display all posts with a matching title, also sorted by date; and so on...

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr

The function query allow you to compute a custom score.

By default the documents will be sorted by their score.
But you can [choose how you want to sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html) those documents.

## Solution

This is going to sort first on the score then by the date (chronologically)

```json
{
  "sort" : [
    "_score",
    { "@timestamp" : {"order" : "asc"}}
  ],
  "query" : {
    ... Your query ...
  }
}
```